# GCM not using data from JSON payload in the notification

Tags: android, push-notification, push, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending the following JSON through GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) but I have not been able to get the right response data through the Client. I get a push notification response, but the title is the App's name, and the texts reads: "message" so I can't display my notification properly.

Here is the JSON that I am trying to send:

```
{  
  "to": "somekey",
  "notification": {  
      "body":"Test",
      "title":"Test"
  },
  "data": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is on the key-values of the *payload* of your message.

As you can see at [GCM Server documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#downstream), the *payload* can be set using two different keys:

- **data**: This parameter specifies the key-value pairs of the **message's** payload.
- **notification**: This parameter specifies the key-value pairs of the **notification** payload.

You should use the **data** key and set inside the *payload* of the notification. Once send, you can print the result of the notification received and see that there are the right payload inside the **data** key.

Your message should be like the following JSON data:

```
{
  "registration_ids" => "some_target_device_id",
  "data": {
      "title": "My title",
      "message": "This is the message!",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Authorization: key= AIz......#GCM project key

{ "data": {
              "title": "Summer Offer.",
              "message": "Click to visit the offer."
          },
              "to" : "Device Token"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please not that code only answers do not fulfill the standards of SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer